# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 port name

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

What is the name of the flat port (that you use for charging) that comes with Samsung Galaxy Tab 2? I bough a USB keyboard and I'm looking forward to buy an adapter for it.

I'll attatch some images of the port I've found on the internet:

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Wikipedia just refers to it as the "Samsung proprietary connector"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Tab_2_%287.0%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to buy a cable that you can use to attach a USB keyboard to that connector, then everywhere I've seen calls it something like a "**30-pin Samsung socket**", and the cables are called something like "**30-pin to USB OTG adapter cable**" or "**USB OTG Adapter Cable for Samsung Galaxy Tab 2**", eg [examples on Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias=mobile&field-keywords=samsung%20galaxy%20tab%20usb%20adapter), or [on eBay.com](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR11.TRC1.A0.Xgalaxy%20tab%20usb&_nkw=galaxy%20tab%20usb&_sacat=0&_from=R40).

Samsung themselves either seem to avoid naming the port when they're selling their official adapters and cables that plug into it, or just call it a "30 Pin": "[Galaxy Tab Adapters](http://reviews.us.samsung.com/7463/N0000482/adapters-reviews/category.htm)" or "[Galaxy Tab™ Data Cable (Charging) USB to 30 Pin](http://reviews.us.samsung.com/7463/ECC1DP0UBEGSTA/samsung-galaxy-tab-data-cable-charging-usb-to-30-pin-reviews/reviews.htm)"

Comment: The Galaxy Tab 2 [user manual](http://blog.clove.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Samsung_Galaxy%20Tab%202%20101%203G%20GT%20P5100%20User%20Manual.pdf) merely calls it the "multifunction jack". Link is to the pdf file. See the diagram on page 17.